# How to calculate daily interest at different rates each day?

Tags: interest-rates, finance-mathematics

I have the following issue:

I need to calculate the daily income of a financial application over a period based on a percentage of a daily financial index. The problem is that for each day, this index has a different value. For example:

```
Date     value
Apr-1    0,048089%
Apr-2    0,045442%
Apr-3    0,041886%
and so on...
Apr-31   0,035450%
```

On April 1, the initial value of the investment was $ 1,000. How much will the total be on April 31st?

Is there a way to get the final value using a single formula?

The way I do today, I need to calculate the day-to-day balance.

Comment: 30 days have September, April, June and November. So by the time April 31st turns up I guess it will have accrued a lot of interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the values are calculated using discrete compounding, you could do the following.

Formula in Excel:

> =PROD(1+A1:A31)*1000

one line in R

> prod(1+df$value)*1000

A word of warning: if you are using this to compound interest rates other than overnight rates, you are on the wrong track.

Anyway, I will vote to close the question since its too basic.

Comment: so basic you forgot to apply day-count convention / year fraction.